# Entity Framework, Load multiple entities by primary key in a single query while still using caching

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a list of primary key ids for a table whose entities I want to pull into EF memory, modify, and then save.

With a single id you would do something like

```
var entity = dbContext.Entity.Find(id);

entity.SomeColumn = "something";

dbContext.SaveChanges()
```

Currently I'm doing something like this to pull all the entities to be modified in one RTT.

```
int[] ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

Entity[] entities = dbContext.Entity
  .Where(c => ids.Contains(c.PrimaryKey))
  .ToArray();
```

Question being, is EF smart enough to know to check caching before going against my db? For instance, if entities 1-4 had already been attached to the context, there should be no db query made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not implicitly.

`Where()` will always query the database. To explicit query the cache you need to use **.Local**:

`dbContext.Entity.Local.Where(...`

This will not hit the database but it will only return entities that have been cached/loaded before.

Good to know: to view the queries define a Log function like this:

`dbContext.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;`

Comment: Interesting thanks; didn't have time to do my own tests so I posted, but I plan to do some then. The `Local` property seems useful, I think I'll make a helper function akin to `Entity.Find` that takes multiple ids and checks the `Local` property first.